# Windows CE 6.0 R3 - Programmatically clear WINS cache

Tags: windows-ce

I want to clear the netbios name cache programmatically in Win CE which is apparently done on a normal windows box with the command nbtstat -R.

I've seen a webpage which states that nbtstat isn't available on Win CE and it helpfully suggests the use of Winsock instead.

(I know this is a long shot!)